# failed to open stream error while installing

Tags: wordpress, error

I am trying to install CiviCRM as a wordpress plugin.  I am using the GoDaddy wordpress dashboard to do this.  I am getting this error (which is just the first error in a list of several that are appearing):

```
    Warning: require(/home/NAME/public_html/wordpress.SITE.com/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-ctype/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: 

No such file or directory in /home/NAME/public_html/wordpress.SITE.com/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70
```

I am looking at the code in file "autoload_real.php"  and line 70 reads:

```
require $file;
```

nowhere else in this file is $file defined.  the directory "/home/NAME/public_html/wordpress.SITE.com/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/composer/" DOES exist, but the rest of the line "../symfony/polyfill-ctype/bootstrap.php" does not.  there are also 3 other errors in eclipse that are indicated and all of those errors are "syntax error: unexpected 'Autoload()'.  The 3 different lines of code that throw this error are:

```
1) self::$loader = $loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader();
2) call_user_func(\Composer\Autoload\ComposerStaticInitdb2000479593e65ef23454e56d74a73f::getInitializer($loader));
3) $includeFiles = Composer\Autoload\ComposerStaticInitdb2000479593e65ef23454e56d74a73f::$files;
```

I'm not really sure what the issue is, as I'm not experienced enough.  Any help from the experts here?  GoDaddy claims the problem is with the plugin file's coding.

Comment: Does it help if you install it from wordpress itself rather than the GoDaddy control panel? There is also an installtion manual, did you follow the steps from there: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/install/wordpress/

Comment: that's the manual i've been following.  and it tells me to install it from the wordpress "install plugins" menu in the wordpress control panel.  that's what i've been doing.  i never used the goDaddy control panel.  i extracted all the CRM files in my wordpress subdomain directory and uploaded them all via FTP using filezilla.

Comment: Okay. I am not very wel known with wordpress.

Comment: I gave up on this issue, I'm sorry guys. It was just an experiment anyway, to look around in the CRM before I started working for the non-profit agency. thank you for replying.